# Zend Framework Magic Method ORDER clause

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is is possible to ad an ORDER BY clause in magic method db results.  From the docs:

```
    $accountsTable = new Accounts();

    $accountsRowset = $accountsTable->find(1234);

    $user1234 = $accountsRowset->current();

    // Use the default reference rule

    // is it possible to add an order to the related tables results?
    $bugsReportedBy = $user1234->findBugs();

    // Specify the reference rule

    $bugsAssignedTo = $user1234->findBugsByEngineer();
```

Comment: are you using `Zend_db` or `doctrine` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of trial and error and YES i am able to add a ORDER BY Clause.  You can pass in an instance of `Zend_Db_Select`

```
$bugsTable = new Bugs() //extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract;
$bugsSelect = $bugsTable->select(); 
$bugsSelect->order('name ASC');    
$bugsReportedBy = $user1234->findBugs($bugsSelect);
```